# How to share files Between RHEL and Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, rhel, file-sharing

I have installed RHEL 5.5 on VIrtual Box and Host system is Ubuntu 12.04. I can access the files of Ubuntu by using the sharing services of Virtual Box.

[image: Virtual Box]

**But how can I access the files of RHEL which is installed on Virtual Box?**

## Network Configuration

RHEL is connected to Ubuntu using Bridged adapter
[image: Network Mode]

Comment: Please specify the network configuration you're using in VirtualBox, it affects the way to solve this drastically.

Comment: here is the same question: http://superuser.com/questions/477590/how-do-i-access-a-folder-inside-my-virtualbox-from-outside/477591#477591

Comment: @Serge Sorry dear Doesn't related to me. Its Windows and Ubuntu mine is Ubuntu and Redhat.

Comment: @DavidKohen I have added requested information.

Comment: It does no matter what host system do you use. with linux as a host you just have one more option - NFS share. In any case you have to set up either ftp/nfs/samba server at your guest system or use ssh to scp files back and forth. Also, there are tools for offline access to virtual disks of various formats

Comment: which one u recommend and less time consuming in installation and configuration and more importantly can u share reading material(HOWTO) for the one u recommend. Thanks dear

Comment: If you need to copy files occasionally only then copying files with `scp` should be enough. Otherwise, I would recommend you to set up `nfs` share inside the guest system. here you can find the step-by-step instructions: http://nfs.sourceforge.net/nfs-howto/

Comment: And this is the docs from RedHat: https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/ch-nfs.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As people in the comments have pointed out, it's possible to use SMB/CIFS,NFS, or use scp. Either of the first two methods requires some set-up, and reading before you attempt it, on your side.  scp doesn't take much learning, but it can be cumbersome.

I'd like to mention one more option: sshfs.  It's based on fuse, and in Ubuntu it should be as easy as **aptitude install sshfs**.  Requires no setup (short of creating a mount-point for the directory structure on the virtualised RHEL instance).